# Getting the form name of Bing

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize, bing

Using Python 2.7.x and Mechanize, I'm trying to get the form name of Bing and do a search:

```
import mechanize

AGENT = mechanize.Browser()
BING = "http://www.bing.com"

def bing_search(query):
    AGENT.open(BING)
    for form in AGENT.forms():
        print form
    AGENT.select_form(name="q")
    AGENT.form["q"] = query
    data = AGENT.submit()
```

The output of this looks like this:

```
C:\Users\z-perkins-thomas\Documents\bin\python\some-type-of-scanner>python querymine.py
<GET http://www.bing.com/search application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <TextControl(q=)>
  <SubmitControl(go=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(qs=ds) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(form=QBLH) (readonly)>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "querymine.py", line 4, in <module>
    bing_search("test")
  File "C:\Users\z-perkins-thomas\Documents\bin\python\some-type-of-scanner\bin\harvest\search_engines\__init__.py", line
55, in bing_search
    AGENT.select_form(name="q")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 524, in select_form
    raise FormNotFoundError("no form matching "+description)
mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching name 'q'

C:\Users\z-perkins-thomas\Documents\bin\python\some-type-of-scanner>
```

As you can see the form names are listed, however trying any of the listed form names doesn't work and outputs that same issue, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you check out the source code of a page you are trying to load (http://www.bing.com/search) you will see yourself that there is no form with name "q" there... There is an input field with that name, so you might select that one.

Comment: @errata The BING constant points towards `http://www.bing.com`

Comment: Indeed. However, the first line of you error shows that you end up with requesting `GET http://www.bing.com/search`. Anyways, even on `bing.com` there is no form with name "q".

Comment: `bing.com/search` redirects to `bing.com/?scope=web&mkt=en-US`, and if there's no form with that name, then what is this `<TextControl(q=)>`?

Comment: It is an input field, not form (`<input class="b_searchbox" id="sb_form_q" name="q" title="Enter your search term" type="search" value="" maxlength="1000" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sw_as" aria-owns="sw_as">`).

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, how can I find the form names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to select form with a name `q` which doesn't exist on bing.com. However, there is an input field with that name.

You should use it like this:

```
def bing_search(query):
    AGENT.open('http://www.bing.com/')
    AGENT.select_form(nr=0)
    AGENT.form['q'] = query
    data = AGENT.submit()
```

Comment: I'm not understanding where the `nr=0` is coming from, but this does work

Comment: `nr=0` will select the first form on the page. You can select it by `id` instead if you want (`form.attrs['id'] === 'some_form_id'`).